# Turn facebook account into normal account

Tags: support

When I registered for stackoverflow.com, I used the option "log in with Facebook". Now I wonder, if someday I delete my Facebook account, what happens with my account here? Does he get deleted too? Or is there a way to transform it in an account with username/passowrd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add other open ID providers to your account. Each of these can identify you, so if you delete your account from one provider, you can still log on.

Manage this from the `my logins` link on your profile page:

[image: my logins]

Answer (score 0):

You can associate another OpenID with your account.

Click on "my logins" in your profile to add another id.